# pick out rows based on conditioned elements

Tags: matlab

I have an Nx3 matrix, and I would like to pick out all the rows where the first and second column satisfy a certain condition. Here is a (non-working) example showing what I want:

```
a = [1 3 0; 2 3 1; 4 9 2];
a = a(a(:, 1)>3 && a(:, 2)>3)
```

Is there somwway to accomplish this without having to resort to a computationally intensive `for`-loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
a = [1 3 0; 2 3 1; 4 9 2];
a = a(a(:, 1)>3 & a(:, 2)>3,:) %you should put element-wise and (&) and put the colon (:) operator which indicates 'all columns'

ans =

 4     9     2
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way to go:

```
ind1=find(a(:,1)>3);
ind2=find(a(:,2)>3);
a=a(intersect(ind1,ind2),:);
```

Answer (score 0):

A for loop is actually not computationally intensive, it's actually linear on the size of your input. Looping through N is the way to go.

Comment: Then I would make a large-enough Mx3 matrix with `zero`, but since I can't guess the correct value of M, then how would I go about removing the remaining Kx3 entries containing only zero?